# Find the password of the man's PC

Tags: password

A man locked his personal computer with a password and wrote some phrases in the hint box kept in his room.

One day, his wife tries to login in his absence using the hints which contained the following in seperate pieces of paper:

> 1 apples
>   1 oranges
>   2 pineapples
>   4 grapes
>   7 bananas
>   7 mangoes
>   8 pomegranates

Can you help the wife find the password?

**Hint 1**: The password consists of *a* word

Comment: Amazing we just triple answered this.. would normally delete my answer but too cool (I see answered 7 sec ago and answered 2 sec ago)

Comment: This is a rather "too easy" puzzle (as seen by the fast replies.) You could have made it (a bit) more difficult by using images of the fruits rather than the names directly. (Note, I did not down-vote it. Difficulty is *not* a quality criterion for puzzles.)

Comment: The password is: "12345".

Comment: @Len I find that it's like that more often than not :P

Comment: @Quark ,I've just realized that the three of you are wrong. That isn't the password. You two are almost at the edge of getting the password while Len is a bit more farther than you two. I think I'll accept the first answer that gets this right.

Comment: @KSmarts , How'd you get that?

Comment: @CoolGuy You're supposed to reply, "That's amazing. I've got the same combination on my luggage!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Password is:

> passion
>  numbers represent letter to use from the associated word;
>  a o i p s s n
>  then unscramble

Comment: Almost there. See my comment to @Quark under the question.

Comment: Justice is served :P the power of the P

Answer (score 8):

The answer is:

> Passion

Explanation:

> Take the letter with position of the leading number. The letters are a, o, i, p, s, s, n. The only one word anagram this gives is passion, which is also a type of fruit.

Answer (score 4):

is it

> Passion

Because:

> For each line take the that manieth letter of the word, and Passion is an anagram of those letters

Comment: Close. See my comment to @Quark under the question.